# What is the most efficient way to store an unknown number of records in a database?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

What is the best way to store data if I don't know in advance how much data I might have?

The application is that I want to keep track of the employment history of a bunch of people, but I don't know how many places each person has worked.  Would it be best to just alot the proper space for an arbitrary maximum of jobs or store it some other way?

I thought about storing the jobs in another table like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629458/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-measurements-with-a-variable-number-of-f); would that be ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,this is "first normal form" in action

You'd have a Person table

- PersonID
- FirstName
- LastName
- ..

and a Job table

- PersonID (FK, PK)
- JobStartDate (PK)
- JobFinishDate
- Title
- Salary
- ...

Have a look at the [free data models here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) for inspiration

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a typical 1 to N relationship.

You have a table that is called "Employees", and a table called "Jobs".

Your job table looks as follow :

```
| id | employee_id | job_title | job_infos... | current_flag | start_date | end_date |
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be best to just alot the proper space for an arbitrary
>   maximum of jobs

Yes. Always try to avoid building arbitrary limitations into your schema. Stay away from this sort of thing:

```
create table employee
(
    id int primary key,
    name text,
    job1_employer text,
    job1_position text,
    job2_employer text,
    job2_position text
);
```

And instead do something like this:

```
create table employee
(
    id int primary key,
    name text,
    ...
);

create table job_history
(
    id int primary key,
    employee_id int references employee,
    employer text,
    position text,
    ...
);
```

So, you've got one row for each employee, plus one row for each employee's past jobs.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `employment_history` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

You probably would want to look at adding a foriegn key between the employment_history.employee_id and employee.id as well.

This structure will let you add as many history records for a given employee without needing to denormalize your data. If you care about employers, you may also find that employment_history.name would be replaced by a employment_history.employer_id with the corresponding employer table setup. This'll let you look at how many past and present employees a company has as well.